# Macbook 13 pro 2019, trying to connect 2 monitors

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, hdmi

I'm using a "[TBI Pro Adapter Adapti-13 Mini USB-C Hub](https://www.ebay.com/itm/TBI-Pro-Adapter-Adapti-13-Mini-USB-C-Hub-/124466151576)" on my macbook 13 pro (2019)
And I wish to connect my 2 PHILIPS monitors (243v5) they are the same but from diffrent years.
I connected them both thru the adapter one with VGA and the other with HDMI and the mac sees them as one monitor, but I would like it to be separated\chained with the macbook lid closed

another this is the adapter is "shooting down" for time to time can it be because of the adapter or maybe the mac book can't hold to "allot of things connected at the same time" (gaming keyboard, mouse, 2 monitor and sometimes ethernet)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thank you all for your time :)

Comment: Switching the HDMI monitor to the other HDMI port should resolve your problem of not being able to extend your desktop across all three displays.  You really should be using HDMI on both displays anyway as this will provide the best video quality.

Comment: I don't think that will work. The manual always shows that all connected monitors have the same image, no matter what port they use.

Comment: @X_841 " I don't think that will work. "  First, that's not how I read the documentation.  The two HDMI outputs appear to be independent and not mirrors of each other.  Second, it doesn't hurt to try.  Third, driving a digital display with an analog VGA input is just a bad idea for a number of reasons.  The computer is producing a digital output that is pixel to pixel accurate, then VGA analog conversion will only "blur" this image, which only gets converted back to digital in the display.  Keeping an all digital path will provide a better image and remove chances for user and other error.

Comment: Sure, giving it a try is a good idea. Your third point is correct, I never questioned that. Yet, the manual only states that this is possible under windows, on macOS it does not show that option. Lets hope the manual is inaccurate and it is possible under macOS as well.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the [manual](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/B1wMOCc8YES.pdf), the adaptor can only output the same video signal to the different connectors at once. This means you can extend your screen once, but not multiple times. Most likely, the Mac does not even see that multiple monitors are connected, instead the adaptor just mirrors the one incoming video signal to multiple video outputs.

To extend your screen multiple times, you would need to get another adaptor or a powered hub.

EDIT: 
As mentioned by @MacGuffin in the comments the manual mentions that this actually is possible under Windows, yet it doesn't show that under macOS. However, trying it with a second HDMI cable instead of the VGA may yield results, although the manual mentions that it should not make a difference - aside from quality.

Since the manual isn't that detailed, I would just try to contact the customer support mentioned at the bottom. They will be able to tell *if* and *how* it is possible to connect multiple monitors with different video outputs on macOS.

---

As a general note: While USB-C offers great bandwidth and speed it is still limited at some point. Plugging in 3 USB-devices, two monitors, 1GB Ethernet and Audio *may* work, but for sure not at maximum speed. It is not only a USB-C limitation, but also the controller in the HUB/adaptor needs to be able to handle all of that.

For testing drive speed I can recommend [BlackMagic Disk Speed Test](https://apps.apple.com/de/app/blackmagic-disk-speed-test/id425264550?mt=12).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I will try the 2 HDMIs option for sure.

Comment: and second, where did you saw the customer support that you mentioned?

Comment: Scroll down to the bottom of the linked manual site (email: support@tbi-pro.com)

Answer (score 1):

All 2019 MacBook Pro officially support one 5k or two 4k displays. You need a second adapter or a better dock (try Thunderbolt) to fix your issue.

> Video Support
> Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display at millions of colors and:
>
> - One display with 5120-by-2880 resolution at 60Hz at over a billion colors
> - Up to two displays with 4096-by-2304 resolution at 60Hz at millions of colors
> - Up to two displays with 3840-by-2160 resolution at 60Hz at over a billion colors

https://support.apple.com/specs/2019